# Array vs Dictionary response structures with JSONDecoder

Tags: swift, generics, codable, jsondecoder

Got the following data model:

```swift
class ResponseMultipleElements<Element: Decodable>: Decodable {
    let statuscode: Int
    let response_type: Int
    let errormessage: String?
    let detailresponse: Element?

}

class Element<T: Decodable>: Decodable {
    let count: String;
    let element: T?
}
```

For the following API response structure:

```
{
    "statuscode": 200,
    "response_type": 3,
    "errormessage": null,
    "detailresponse": {
        "count": "1",
        "campaigns": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Foo",
                "targetagegroup": null,
                "creator":...
                ...
            }
      }
}
```

I'm triggering JSONDecoder like this:

```swift
class APIService: NSObject {   

func getCampaignList(completion: @escaping(Result<[Campaign], APIError>) -> Void) {

            guard let endpoint = URL(string: apiBaseUrlSecure + "/campaignlist") else {fatalError()}
            var request = URLRequest(url: endpoint)
            request.addValue("Bearer " + UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "authtoken")!, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
            request.httpMethod = "GET"

            let dataTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
                guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpResponse.statusCode == 200, let jsonData = data
                    else { print("ERROR: ", error ?? "unknown error"); completion(.failure(.responseError)); return }
                do {
                    let response = try JSONDecoder().decode(ResponseMultipleElements<[Campaign]>.self, from: jsonData)
                    completion(.success(response.detailresponse!))

                } catch {
                    print("Error is: ", error)
                    completion(.failure(.decodingError))
                }
            }
            dataTask.resume()
        }
 ...
}
```

And I'm finally trying to make use of the decoded campaign object like this

```swift
class CoopOverviewViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //do stuff

        // load Campaigns
        self.apiService.getCampaignList(completion: {result in
            switch result {
            case .success(let campaigns):
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    print("CAMPAIGN DATA: ", campaigns[0].name)
                }
            case .failure(let error):
                print("An error occured \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        })

 ...
}
```

Now I've got 2 questions:

1)

```
let element: T?
```

is actually called "campaigns" in the api response for this call. However, it could be cooperations, payments, etc. in other api responses with that same ResponseMultipleElements surrounding structure. Is there a way to make the key swappable here, like I've done with the value with the use of generics? If not, how else would I solve that problem?

2) I'm getting this error:

```
typeMismatch(Swift.Array<Any>, 
Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: 
[CodingKeys(stringValue: "detailresponse", intValue: nil)], 
debugDescription: "Expected to decode Array<Any> but found a dictionary instead.", underlyingError: nil))
```

I've told Swift that the "campaigns" part of the detailresponse is an Array of campaign objects - at least that's my understanding when looking at the api response. However, the error seems to say it's a dictionary. First, I don't get why that is and would really like to understand it. Second, I don't know how to tell it that it should expect a dictionary instead of an array then - getting confused with generics here a bit.

Thank you so much for your help in advance!

Comment: Is the value `response_type` related to the different keys `campaigns`, `cooperations` etc? If yes declare `response_type` as enum and decode the type depending on the enum. And if there is a fixed number of different types even the generic is nonessential.

Comment: This cannot work. My question was: Does  `3` in `response_type` in the root object represent `campaigns` and other values represent the other types?

Comment: In my initial question, in class Element, I'm having a property with a key named "element". That key could be campaigns or cooperations or whatever array of objects is returned by the api, subject to the called endpoint. This does not correspond to the response_type in any way. I've started with making the type of that object generic but can't figure out how to do the same with the key. Is there a solution for that?

Comment: Please see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an approach to add a custom key decoding strategy to map any `CodingKey` but `count` in `detailresponse` to fixed value `element`.

First of all create a custom `CodingKey`

```
struct AnyCodingKey: CodingKey {

    var stringValue: String

    init?(stringValue: String) {
        self.stringValue = stringValue
    }

    var intValue: Int? { return nil }

    init?(intValue: Int) {
        return nil
    }
}
```

Then create the structs similar to Sh_Khan's answer, in most cases classes are not needed

```
struct ResponseMultipleElements<T: Decodable>: Decodable {
    let statuscode : Int
    let response_type : Int
    let errormessage : String?
    let detailresponse : Element<T>
}

struct Element<U: Decodable>: Decodable {
    let count : String
    let element : U
}

struct Campaign : Decodable {
    let id : Int
    let name : String
    let targetagegroup : String?
}
```

Now comes the funny part. Create a custom key decoding strategy which returns always `element` for the CodingKey in `detailresponse` which is not `count`

```
do {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .custom { codingKeys in
        let lastKey = codingKeys.last!
        if lastKey.intValue != nil || codingKeys.count != 2 { return lastKey }
        if lastKey.stringValue == "count" { return lastKey }
        return AnyCodingKey(stringValue: "element")!
    }
    let result = try decoder.decode(ResponseMultipleElements<[Campaign]>.self, from: data)
    completion(.success(result.detailresponse.element))
} catch {
    print("Error is: ", error)
    completion(.failure(error))
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Works like a charmer and taught me a lesson about custom decoding strategy. Thank you SO much!!!